# "bazel test //..." executes actions unrelated to any tests

Tags: bazel

I have a target `//src/hello:hello_proj.bit` which should not be a dependency for any tests.  This is confirmed by:

```
$ bazel cquery 'rdeps(//..., //src/hello:hello_proj.bit)' --output=label_kind
INFO: Analyzed 38 targets (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 38 targets...
vivado_bitstream rule //src/hello:hello_proj.bit (43fd5e3)
vivado_config_memory rule //src/hello:hello_proj.bin (43fd5e3)
vivado_load rule //src/hello:hello_proj.load (43fd5e3)
vivado_flash rule //src/hello:hello_proj.flash (43fd5e3)
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.175s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 0 total actions
```

And:

```
$ bazel cquery 'allpaths(tests(//...), //src/hello:hello_proj.bit)'
INFO: Analyzed 38 targets (0 packages loaded, 3 targets configured).
INFO: Found 38 targets...
INFO: Empty query results
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.247s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 0 total actions
```

In addition, the following returns no results:

```
$ bazel aquery 'deps(tests(//...))' | grep hello_proj.bit
```

But yet the following still tries to build `//src/hello:hello_proj.bit` even though the tests can complete successfully if `--keep_going` is issued.  So clearly it is not truly a dependecy but ends up in the action graph for some unknown reason.

```
$ bazel test -s --keep_going //...
INFO: Analyzed 35 targets (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 26 targets and 9 test targets...
SUBCOMMAND: # //src/hello:hello_proj.bit [action 'Synthesizing hello', configuration: 0decb71fa64362af97ee459b2292a0b5285d3f4092bf077905729774dcbbdb43, execution platform: @local_config_platform//:host]
... Removed for brevity ...
ERROR: /home/agoessling/hdl/src/hello/BUILD:26:15: Synthesizing hello failed (Exit 1):
... Removed for brevity ...
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.339s, Critical Path: 0.18s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
//src/hello:test_hello_ver_BAUD25000000_FREP100000              (cached) PASSED in 0.4s
//src/lib:prove_strobe_div                                      (cached) PASSED in 1.0s
//src/lib:prove_uart_tx                                         (cached) PASSED in 4.2s
//src/lib:test_strobe_div_DIV100                                (cached) PASSED in 0.4s
//src/lib:test_strobe_div_DIV2                                  (cached) PASSED in 0.4s
//src/lib:test_strobe_div_DIV6                                  (cached) PASSED in 0.3s
//src/lib:test_strobe_div_DIV7                                  (cached) PASSED in 0.3s
//src/lib:test_strobe_div_DIV8                                  (cached) PASSED in 0.4s
//src/lib:test_uart_tx_BAUD_DIV3                                (cached) PASSED in 0.4s

Executed 0 out of 9 tests: 9 tests pass.
All tests passed but there were other errors during the build.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I'm at a loss at what else to try to dig into this.  No `query`, `cquery`, or `aquery` that I have tried has yielded any connection from any test to `//src/hello:hello_proj.bit`.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In bazel, the `test` verb is essentially "build the given targets and execute any of them that are tests".

`//...` expands to all targets in the current workspace, which therefore includes `//src/hello:hello_proj.bit`

So here bazel is building everything (`//...`) and then running any tests.

To build just the test cases, pass [--build_tests_only](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/3.7.0/command-line-reference.html#flag--build_tests_only)

Comment: If you want to make this mode the default for yourself or a project, add `test --build_tests_only` to the appropriate [bazelrc](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/guide.html#bazelrc-the-bazel-configuration-file).

Comment: Hmm interesting. I thought it was more find all the tests, then build all the dependenices of the tests, then run the tests.