# Bazel test ... runs targets that are not test targets

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I am getting started with Bazel, and I came across this problem:

I have a Bazel package with a python library, and it's `BUILD.bazel` file declares three targets: `py_library`, `py_test`, and a "`my_own_target`". That latter `my_own_target` is declared in a separate package called `my_bazel_tools`. That package declares a toolchain that downloads a specific executable for the current platform, which is required for the things I want to do with my library. That `my_bazel_tools` package also declares some custom rules and the `my_own_target` macro that uses those rules.

All those rules and macros work fine when I call them specifically. However, when I run `bazel test ...` either from the root of the project or from my python library folder, the steps of the toolchain rules and my custom rules are also run, which is not what I want.

I tried adding "test = False" to my rules declarations, but that didn't help. My `py_test` target does not depend on the toolchain, the `py_library` target does not depend on the toolchain or my custom rules either.

Is there any way I can prevent the toolchains and custom rules from running when I run `bazel test ...`?

Comment: If you are looking to exclude some of the files then [look](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2460)

Comment: This is the default behaviour of bazel, see related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65053900/bazel-test-executes-actions-unrelated-to-any-tests/65054238#65054238

Comment: @BenjaminPeterson Both yes and no. It tells me why this is happening, but not what I can do about it. However, understanding why something happens is a good starting point. Thank you.

Comment: `--build_tests_only` doesn't suffice?

Comment: @BenjaminPeterson Yes, it does work.